# multiple star rating with for loop and submit form

Tags: vue.js

I use a star rating system to answer questions. I use a loop of answers because I have several questions. I do not use a "store" for the star rating system. How can I use this module without going through the "store" because when I click on the star system, it never goes back to 0.

my template :

```
<div v-if="question.element_type=='notation'">
  <star-rating 
    inactive-color="#4c514c" 
    v-bind:star-size="30"
    v-model="selectedNote"
    @rating-selected ="setRating"
    :rounded-corners="true"
    :show-rating="false">
  </star-rating>
  <b-input @input="nextContent" v-model="selectedNote" class="myHiddenInput" maxlength="1" :name="'q'+question.id"></b-input>
</div>
```

my onSubmit:

```
var serialize = require('form-serialize');
var form = el.target;
var reponsesJSON = serialize(form, { hash: true })
```

Comment: what is a store?

Comment: A "store" is basically a container that holds your application state